# Why does Xcode fail to compile when opened from command line?

Tags: xcode

I get this build error

`i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1: /Users/soheil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Get_iPlayer_GUI-fqsfzttzsuikevhdogsnxnjaddjn/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Get_iPlayer GUI_Prefix-hggnypajoaggzffgvymocdlipqdj/Get_iPlayer GUI_Prefix.pch.dia: No such file or directory`

```
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-implicit-atomic-properties"
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-receiver-is-weak"
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-deprecated-implementations"
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-sign-conversion"
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-fserialize-diagnostics"
Command /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

when opening some xcode projects from command line like

```
open Get_iPlayer\ GUI.xcodeproj/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Unsure if it's related to your problem, but the command line tools are a separate install which can be done in Preferences/Downloads inside XCode.

Comment: post the exact command and the actual text of the error?

Comment: I have the same problem: typing "open fast-dm.xcodeproj" opens xcode, but compiling fails with error messages like the ones you show.  In contrast, after opening xcode by clicking on "fast-dm.xcodeproj" in the finder window compilation works.  Very mysterious.  Maybe some environment variables are leaked from the shell into xcode and mess things up?

Comment: As a sidenote: Are you unable to open this project normally *(as in: from the Mac OS X GUI)*?  I guess I'm not seeing the benefit of opening this project from the command line... *(if you are just going to use the GUI tools after opening the project...)*

Comment: Just to check: does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and for me the reason was that I set the CC environment variable to "gcc" in my shell startup files.  Starting Xcode as follows works for me:

```
unset CC
open fast-dm.xcodeproj
```

If I only give the second command, compilation in Xcode fails with error messages very similar to the ones you saw.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
open -a Xcode folder/project.xcode
```

`-a` stands for application. Here you open the project with the application **Xcode**.